# Inner join on the same columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Customer  Table
----------------------
CustomerName
Peter
Sam


Sales Table
-----------------------
ProductName    Customer
Cloth          Peter
Mobile         Peter
Cloth          Sam
Laptop         Sam
```

Expected result

```
Customer
Sam
```

I want result as customer who buyed 'Cloths' but not 'Mobile', i tried

```
select c.CustomerName from Customer c inner join Sales s1 on (s1.customer = c.customername and s1.productname = 'Cloth') inner join Sales s2 on (s2.customer = c.customername and s2.productname != 'Mobile');
```

but it always return both entries

```
Customer
Peter
Sam
Sam
```

Answer (score 2):

A correlated subquery would be better as you're not interested in getting multiple rows for customers who bought cloths multiple times.

```
select
  c.CustomerName
from
  Customer c
where
  exists (
    select null
    from   sales
    where  sales.customer = c.customername and
           s1.productname = 'Cloth') and
  not exists (
    select null
    from   sales
    where  sales.customer = c.customername and
           s1.productname = 'Mobile');
```

Comment: Thanks @David is this not possible with innerjoins?

Comment: You would have to outer join to sales to find sales for "Mobile" and then eliminate from the result any that you found records for, and inner join for "Cloth", and then DISTINCT the result set. It wouldn't be at all as efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Oracle [`MINUS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) operator to make it simple;

```
SELECT "Customer" FROM SalesTable WHERE "ProductName"='Cloth'
MINUS
SELECT "Customer" FROM SalesTable WHERE "ProductName"='Mobile'
```

Another slightly more complex option is a `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1."Customer"
FROM SalesTable s1
LEFT JOIN SalesTable s2
ON s1."Customer" = s2."Customer"
   AND s2."ProductName" = 'Mobile'
WHERE s1."ProductName" = 'Cloth'
  AND s2."Customer" IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test both with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5ee1/1).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I think a good approach is to use aggregation:

```
select s.Customer
from Sales s
group by s.Customer
having sum(case when s.ProductName = 'Cloth' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- has cloth
       sum(case when s.ProductName = 'Mobile' then 1 else 0 end) = 0     -- does not have mobile
```

I prefer putting the logic in the `having` clause, because it is quite flexible.  You can add additional conditions quite easily for other products.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select c.CustomerName 
from Customer c 
where exists(select 1 from sales s1 where s1.customer = c.customername and s1.productname = 'Cloth')
and not exists (select 1 from sales s2 where s2.customer = c.customername and s2.productname = 'Mobile')
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should review your database schema.
You never do inner join without an id.
Try to create your tables using relationships. Like this:

```
create table customer
(
id_customer       int not null,
ds_customername   varchar(80) null,
primary key (id_customer)
)

create table products
(
id_product  int not null,
ds_product  varchar(100) null,
primary key (id_product)
)

create table sales
(
id_sales    int not null,
id_product  int not null,
id_customer int not null,
foreign key (id_product) references products (id_product),
foreign key (id_customer) references customer (id_customer)
)

select  customer.ds_customername
from    customer
        inner join sales (customer.id_customer = sales.id_customer)
        inner join products (products.id_product = sales.id_product)
where   products.ds_product = 'Cloth'
```

Ok,
if you can't do this, you can do your query (in an old way) this:

```
    select   Customer.customername
    from     Customer
             inner join on (customer.customername = sales.customer)
    where    sales.productname = 'Cloth'
```

I hope help you.
Hugs,
Vin.